# Localizing text from XML files

Tags: localization, xml, xgettext

Do you guys know any way I could automatically pick up strings from .xml files and store them in a .po / .pot file, just like PoEdit does with the ones from .php files?

The XML structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<options>
  <page id="content" label="Content Options" icon="4">
    <section id="post" label="Content Options">
      <option id="title" type="checkbox" default="yes" label="Show post title"></option>
      <option id="comments" type="checkbox" default="yes" label="Show comments link"></option>
      <option id="thumb_size" type="select" default="default" label="Thumbnail Size">
        <value id="default" label="Default Size, (%s)" vars="default_size"></value>
        <value id="100x100" label="Small (100x100)"></value>
        <value id="150x150" label="Medium (150x150)"></value>
        <value id="200x200" label="Large (200x200)"></value>
      </option>

    </section>
  </page>
</options>
```

Strings within the "label" attribute should be detected by a gettext parser or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a localized XML format like `XLIFF` or `TMX` , there is a tool to convert XLIFF to .po.

If you cannot change the source XML you have a few options but it really depends how your outputting this XML info:

1. Parse the XML ( for label) and create a .po with gettext output for these strings (then possibly merge the .po files).
2. Duplicate the XML and insert the `_()` gettext right into the XML, then parse it on output.

Also have a look at this tool, and there are some command line python tools that can convert xml-->po I think, http://itstool.org/

Comment: thanks. I found a work-around for PoEdit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307612/poedit-and-xml-files and http://zendschool.com/tag/poedit/ (the text needs to inside a new element though)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to try itstool, you just need to give it a custom ITS rules file for your format. The following rules works for the snippet you posted:

```
<its:rules
    xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its"
    its:version="1.0">
  <its:translateRule translate="yes" selector="//@label"/>
</its:rules>
```

Save this as, say, options.its, then run itstool like this:

```
itstool -i options.its -o somefile.pot somefile.xml
```

After your translators have translated and given you a PO file (say, xx.po), compile it to an mo file, then merge using itstool:

```
msgfmt -o xx.mo xx.po
itstool -m xx.mo -i options.its -o somefile.xx.xml somefile.xml
```

Check the documentation for more: http://itstool.org/documentation/